# HTML Layout for Grouping Two or More Lines

Tags: html, css

I want to make layout that can display 2 lines. It looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, |
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, |
```

When I resize my browser, this is what I get:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
consectetuer adipiscing elit|
,                           |
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
consectetuer adipiscing elit|
,                           |
```

However **this is what I want it to look like**:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
consectetuer adipiscing elit|
consectetuer adipiscing elit|
,                           |
,                           |
```

How can I make my desired layout possible? thank you.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Is there a practical application for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have more than 2 elements, you'll need to adjust the math for the top/line-height values.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/fhthacxq

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>

body { /* container element */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 2.5em; /* top * number of elements */
  margin-bottom: 1.25em; /* same as top */
}

p + p {
  top: 1.25em; /* 1em + distance from previous line */
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think your solution is better than mine. I had not considered this.

Comment: It's not a great solution since it uses absolute positioning (which impacts how everything around it flows), but it's probably the best way to go while remaining semantically pure and making sense when unstyled.

Comment: Actually this question makes no sense, he is breaking the sentence in a wrong way, though solution is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Using only HTML and CSS, you need to arrange the text into columns of words to achieve the effect you want. This is is because you are essentially changing the ordering of the words, and so they need to be grouped differently.

Below is an example.

**HTML:**

```
<div>Lorem<br/>Lorem</div>
<div>ipsum<br/>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor<br/>dolor</div>
<div>sit<br/>sit</div>
<div>amet<br/>amet</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wZxs8/)**